# Solidity: How to test if a function is called from another contract?

Tags: blockchain, solidity, chai

I was wondering how I can test if a function is called from another contract using chai.

Contracts will be like:

```
contract ContractA {
  function shouldBeCalledByOthers() { // some code... };
}

contract ContractB {
  ContractA contractA;

  constructor(address addr) {
    contractA = ContractA(addr);
  }

  function shouldCallA() {
    contractA.shouldBeCalledByOthers();
  }
}
```

Then I would like to test if ContractA's `shouldBeCalledByOthers` method is called when ContractB's `shouldCallA` method is called.

Can chai spy be used for this purpose?
https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-spies/

Answer (score 0):

In Solidity, you can verify if the function caller is a contract or not:

```
modifier callerIsUser() {
  require(tx.origin == msg.sender, "The caller is another contract");
  _;
}

function example() callerIsUser {
  ...
}
```